# Tengo este código pero me falta calcular la complejidad temporal de la función indexOf

Tags: java

Éste es el código, la siguiente función java recibe como entrada dos cadenas texto y patrón, y retorna la primera posición de texto en la que se encuentra patrón. En caso de que patrón no se encuentre, retorna -1.

El tiempo de ejecución depende de m como de n

```java
void indexOf(String text, String pattern) { 
    int n = text.length();
    int m = pattern.length();
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - m; i++) {          
            int j;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            if (text.charAt(i + j) != pattern.charAt(j))
                break;
        if (j == m)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: ya que se asume (n-m) = z por lo que se aplica la misma complejidad temporal de un siclo anidado según el paso (n-m)*m iteraciones, dando nm-m2 [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ba8a5tL4I0)